# How to execute bash script after rsync

Tags: bash, unix, rsync

When I deploy on my dev server I use rsync. But after rsync I need to execute a .sh file for "after" deploy operations like clear cache...

Usually I do this via SSH, but if I deploy very often it's boring write:

- ssh ...
- write password
- cd /var/www/myapp/web
- ./after_deploy.sh

There is a way to do this quickly? This is my rsync.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=""
directory="/var/www/myapp/web"
password=""
usage(){
        echo "Cant do rsync";
        echo "Using:";
        echo "   $0 direct";
        echo "Or:";
        echo "   $0 dry";
}
echo "Host: $host";
echo "Directory: $directory"
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        if [ "$1" == "dry" ]; then
                echo "DRY-RUN mode";
                rsync -CvzrltD --force --delete --exclude-from="app/config/rsync_exclude.txt" -e "sshpass -p '$password' ssh -p22" ./ $host:$directory --dry-run
        elif [ "$1" == "direct" ]; then
                echo "Normal mode";
                rsync -CvzrltD --force --delete --exclude-from="app/config/rsync_exclude.txt" -e "sshpass -p '$password' ssh -p22" ./ $host:$directory
        else
                usage;
        fi;
else
        usage;
fi
```

Comment: The shell script has to be executed on your host system or remotely?

Comment: It has to be executed remotely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a command after the `rsync` command to execute it instead of starting a shell.

Add the following after the rsync command :

```
sshpass -p "$password" ssh $host "cd $dir && ./after_deploy.sh"
```

Comment: Can you help me to replace better your line with mine? I cant replace it without errors...I think quotes errors.

Answer (score 4):

If instead of using rsync over SSH, you can run an rsync daemon on the server. This allows you to use the `pre-xfer exec` and `post-xfer exec` options in `/etc/rsyncd.conf` to specify a command to be run before and/or after the transfer.

For example, in /etc/rsyncd.conf:

```
[myTransfers]
     path = /path/to/stuff
     auth users = username
     secrets file = /path/to/rsync.secrets
     pre-xfer exec = /usr/local/bin/someScript.sh
     post-xfer exec = /usr/local/bin/someOtherscript.sh
```

You can then do the transfer from the client machine, and the relevant scripts will be run automatically on the server, for example:

```
rsync -av . username@hostname::myTransfers/
```

This approach may also be useful because environment variables relating to the transfer on the server can also be used by the scripts.

See https://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf for more information.